# IIS replace part of url

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis-7.5

I'm trying to replace "se" with "sv" in a url by using url rewrite in iis.

Url look like this: www.somedomain.com/**se**/baadmarked/baade

And should look like this: www.somedomain.com/**sv**/baadmarked/baade

My current rule look like this:

```
<rule name="se to sv" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="(.*)" />
    <action type="Redirect" url="{C:1}sv{C:3}" appendQueryString="false" />
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="(.*)(se)(.*)" />
    </conditions>
</rule>
```

I've tried a lot, but nothing gets the job done.

Answer (score 5):

It sounds like you want to use the Rewrite feature and not the Redirect feature.

The rule should look like this:

```
<rule name="se to sv">
    <match url="^(.*)/se/(.*)" />
    <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:1}/sv/{R:2}" />
</rule>
```

The match is breaking the rule into two parts. The first part is the domains and the second part is everything after the `se`.

The action is saying to rewrite all of these address to `{R:1}` The domain part, `/sv/` then `{R:2}` everything after the `se`.

If you did want Redirect just change the action from `Rewrite` to `Redirect`. It's not very clear.

You can still add `stopProcessing="true"` and `appendQueryString="false"` if you need.

Comment: I tried the rule, it didn't apply. Maybe something else is wrong in my setup, cause i agree the rule should be like that. When i use the built in "Test pattern" it also applies the rule perfectly.

Comment: How did you install UrlRewrite? WebPI? I also have issues with WebPI, on the download page you should be able to download the x64 or x86 installers.