# Replace one word of domain URL in IIS

Tags: c#, iis, url-rewriting, http-redirect

I moved my project to a new server (from abc.com/eco to abc2.com/eco) and created a HTTP redirect rule to redirect every abc.com/eco requests to abc2.com/eco. which works fine on abc.com/eco requests.

[image]

The problem is, Urls after eco does not get redirected.

**For example**:
abc.com/eco/departments/main.aspx?id=123

does not redirect to

abc2.com/eco/departments/main.aspx?id=123

The following **Url rewrite rule** doesnt work also:

```
<rule name="Redirects to abc2.com" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="true">

    <match url=".*" />

    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">

        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^abc.*(com|net)$" />

    </conditions>

    <action type="Redirect" url="http://abc2.com/{R:0}" />

</rule>
```

I looked over tens of questions but all are asking about the subdirectory replace.

**Similar questions** but not answering mine:

[Question 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55456611/iis-url-rewrite-rule-to-replace-part-of-the-url)

[Question 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39368393/iis-replace-part-of-url)

Comment: Study URL Rewrite module and it will help, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/creating-rewrite-rules-for-the-url-rewrite-module

Comment: @LexLi I actually know about the url rewrite module but dont know how to use the wildcard on the actual domain and not the subdirectories

Comment: "dont know how to use the wildcard on the actual domain and not the subdirectories" What's that? Maybe you should post a separate question with the rule you tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rule is working properly on my side.

Have you cleaned cache before testing a new rewrite rule with long term permanent redirect.

If you didn't clean the browser cache, your previous HTTP redirection will keep redirecting your URL to http://abc2/eco

[image]

Comment: you are right. and I actually changed the action to <action type="Redirect" url="http://abc2.com/eco/{R:1}" /> and it works perfect.